# Identifier syntax

Tags: core-language

In formal programming we call the symbols used to represent variable or other objects *identifiers*. What is commonly called a "variable" is a kind of identifier. Identifiers are also used for function names. In general, an identifier is anything that the programmer can define, as opposed to symbols which are defined by the language.

Apparently there is no formal specification for the Wolfram Language, so I am asking here if anyone knows what the allowable characters are in Wolfram Language identifiers?

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica any sequence of letters or letter-like forms can be used as a programmer-defined symbol (aka identifier), providing the lexical scanner can't find any previously defined interpretation for it. However, considering all the built-in symbols Mathematica has, the user is much constrained by this limitation.

For example, some of things you can't use a identifiers because of built-in interpretations are:

```
42abc
```

which is interpreted as

> `42*abc`

This seems to be a special rule, because, as I'm sure you know, `abc42` is fine. It is almost certainly allowed so expressions such as `1 + 2x0 + 4x0^2` can be entered and get their expected interpretation.

Further, any sequence containing a subsequence that will be interpreted as an operator won't do. Familiar examples, allowed by other languages, being

`my_identifier`

> `Pattern[my, Blank[identifier]]`

and

```
my.identifier
```

> `Dot[my, identifier]`

On the other hand, character sequences that a lot of other languages would not allow can be identifiers in Mathematica. For example,

```
a \[ShortRightArrow] b = 42
```

> `42`

and

```
m\[DoubleDot]n = Sqrt[a \[ShortRightArrow] b]
```

> `Sqrt[42]`

which in a notebook show up as

[image: OK]

Comment: Symbols / Details / 3rd bullet point. Failed to find other official source of restrictions.

Comment: @Kuba. There is more information scattered among the documentation articles linked to by [this article](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalAndOtherNotationOverview.html). I know of no formal, complete statement of the rules. I am summarizing what I know from reading the docs and my own experience with Mathematica.